# Difference between ServerMonitorListener and ServerListener and AutoReconnect | MongoDB

Tags: java, database, mongodb, server-monitoring

i am trying to implement the MongoDB Java API and wanted to know the exact difference between ServerMonitorListener and ServerListener.

Maybe you can tell me the difference and also tell me why it is useful to use the specific one?

Also which one of these two is better to determinate if the connection is still up and how to add an autoreconnect if it is closed?

Kind Regards

Fabian Schmidt

Comment: Seems like a question that is not answerable haha

Comment: You don't need to concern yourself with these details, the Java driver will automatically handle the reconnect for you, by default.